# System date change tracking in windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, date, event-viewer

I wanted to track when system time was changed in a PC.By looking at event viewer for event id 520 i will get it. But when i changed date manually in windows and look at event viewer i found 4 entries for a single date change.

[image]

Now In that 4 entries last one has below description

```
The system time was changed.
 Process ID:    1932
 Process Name:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe
 Primary User Name: nav
 Primary Domain:    PC132
 Primary Logon ID:  (0x0,0x115A0)
 Client User Name:  nav
 Client Domain: PC132
 Client Logon ID:   (0x0,0x115A0)
 Previous Time: 10:18:32 AM 8/23/2013
 New Time:  10:18:32 AM 8/24/2013
```

All other three entries shows

```
The system time was changed.
 Process ID:    1932
 Process Name:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe
 Primary User Name: navaneeth a
 Primary Domain:    PC132
 Primary Logon ID:  (0x0,0x115A0)
 Client User Name:  navaneeth a
 Client Domain: PC132
 Client Logon ID:   (0x0,0x115A0)
 Previous Time: 10:18:32 AM 8/24/2013
 New Time:  10:18:32 AM 8/24/2013
```

What is the meaning of these 4 entries for a date change?

Also is there any method to get system date changed history or log?

Answer (score 0):

To explain Event ID -520 :

**Process Name** : Path and name of the process that changed the time.  Will usually be rundll32.exe (Control Panel), cmd.exe (Time command) or svchost (if the time was changed by the system in connection with the Windows time synchronization service or NTP)

**Primary User Name**: Will correspond to local system if changed automatically; otherwise will identify the actual user if changed through control panel or the time command.

**Primary Domain** : domain of the user

**Primary Logon ID**: correlates to the logon ID in the user's logon session event ID 528 or 540

**Client User Name** :your log in name

**Client Domain** : your internal domain

**Client Logon ID** :logon id

**Previous Time**: Previous system time

**New Time** : Current changed time

In addition to it the fourth entry has event id : 515

From [technet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows%20Operating%20System&ProdVer=5.0&EvtID=515&EvtSrc=Security&LCID=1033) :

This event record indicates that a logon process has registered with the Local Security Authority (LSA). Also, logon requests will now be accepted from this source.Logon processes are trusted components responsible for collecting identification and authentication information from external devices, such as terminals and networks. They use Local Security Authority services to log these users on. A single system can simultaneously support multiple logon processes.

Your system date

Alternatively you can try [myeventviewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/my_event_viewer.html) for keep tracking the changes.

i guess overwrite is disabled at event-viewer properties,so the logs might  get logged multiple times

Comment: These are just explanation about what each details refer to. But i want to know why 4 events are written in event viewer if i change date only once?